How do I determine if a string has been localized or not?
I've got my app localized (English and Spanish) except that not all strings are translated.  This is the code I'm using and seems to work well.
      public static string? TextOrNull(string? ResourceFile, string ResourceID, CultureInfo thisCulture)
      {
         string? txt = null;
         try
         {
            if ((ResourceFile != null) && (ResourceID != null))
            {
               txt = GetResourceManager(ResourceFile)?.GetString(ResourceID, thisCulture);
               if ((txt != null) && (txt.Equals(string.Empty)))
                  txt = null;
            }
         }
         catch
         {
            txt = null;
         }

         return (txt);
      }

I'd like to know if the string returned from GetString is from the resource file associated with the given culture.  Specifically, if the given culture is 'es-mx' but there is no Spanish text, I get English (appropriate behavior).  Is there a way to know when this happens?
Thanks
I'm a native English speaker developing a .NET Maui app using VS 2022 Community 64 bit edition - 17.10.1
I can't find anything in the documentation nor any examples.

If the output string is the same as the input string then it hasn’t been localized?

The input is a resource id ... the output is the string associated with that id.

What is GetResourceManager  method?  Do you use any third-party nuget?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-resources-resourcemanager-getobject

Thanks for response. GetString will return the default culture's value if the ResourceID is not found. It won't throw the exception. You may not catch it.

Exactly.  So, there doesn't appear to be any way to tell what if I get the string from the requested culture or the default.

But you may set a special value for the key which has no value for the requested culture. And detect if GetString  return the special value.

I went the other way and defined special keys in resource files for the Spanish-Mexico culture.  So, I can tell if TTS should use a Spanish voice or English voice.  I'm not sure there is a solution for apps that use more than two cultures.  Further, the solution requires the entire resource file to be translated.  It would be nice if there was a way to get a string from a given culture that does not use the fallbacks.
